# How to schedule a Foxpro report to run at a certain time?

Tags: foxpro

I need a FoxPro report to run every day in certain time. How can I achieve that? I don't need to do anything else with the report just run in in certain time.

Answer (score 3):

You can run something in windows in certain time with [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)
which can run process with arguments. So if your report action is only part of application written in FoxPro you have to move (rewrite) this code to individual application or process [command line parameters](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1752644) in your application.